# How to use polling with wmq-inbound connector in mule?

Tags: mule, ibm-mq, polling

Sample example is :

```
<flow name="testFlow">
    <poll doc:name="Poll">
      <fixed-frequency-scheduler frequency="10000" startDelay="10"/>
      <wmq:inbound-endpoint queue="${mq.ssl.mvs.queue1}" connector-ref="wMQConfig1" doc:name="WMQ"/>
    </poll>
      <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>    
</flow>
```

I get following error:

```
org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentInitException: SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'wmq:inbound-endpoint'. One of '{"http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-poll-override, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-message-processor, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-outbound-endpoint, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-mixed-content-message-processor}' is expected. at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:205)
~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0] at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper$2.execute(ArtifactWrapper.java:63)
~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0] at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.executeWithinArtifactClassLoader(ArtifactWrapper.java:136)
~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0] at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.init(ArtifactWrapper.java:58) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0] at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:25)
~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0] at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.guardedDeploy(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:324)
~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0] at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:345)
~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0] at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:163)
~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0] at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:268)
~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0] at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:83)
~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0] at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.deployPackedApps(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:275)
~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0] at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.start(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:150)
~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0] at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleDeploymentService.start(MuleDeploymentService.java:104)
~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0] at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleContainer.start(MuleContainer.java:170)
~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.0.jar:3.8.0] at org.mule.tooling.server.application.ApplicationDeployer.main(ApplicationDeployer.java:15)
~[tooling-support-3.8.0.jar:?]
```

Comment: This is only about failed validation of your flow xml file. Have you declared wmq namespace there? Anyway, it makes sense to include it (the full) into the question.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a Poll wrapped wmq:inbound-endpoint as your message source. If you are reading from the WebSphereMQ you will need to change this to a wmq:outbound-endpoint component else move it to the process flow section.